# Is there a way to scale an element and then rotate it while it is scaled then bring it back to its original size

Tags: css, animation, rotation, css-animations

I am trying to scale the whole page, then rotate it while it is scaled, and then bring it back to its original size. Yet when the rotation starts it brings the page to its original size to rotate it while I want it to rotate while scaled. I hope I'm making sense with the explanation.

```
''' 
@keyframes rotating {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes shrinkingback {
    0% {
        -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
        -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
        -o-transform: scale(0.5);
        transform: scale(0.5);
    }
    100% {
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        -o-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    
}
@keyframes shrinking {
    0% {
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        -o-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    100% {
        -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
        -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
        -o-transform: scale(0.5);
        transform: scale(0.5);
    }
    
}
body {
         
    -webkit-animation: shrinking 3s, rotating 5s linear 3s, shrinkingback 3s 8s;
    -moz-animation: shrinking 3s, rotating 5s linear 3s, shrinkingback 3s 8s;
    -ms-animation:  shrinking 3s, rotating 5s linear 3s, shrinkingback 3s 8s;
    -o-animation:  shrinking 3s, rotating 5s linear 3s, shrinkingback 3s 8s;
    animation: shrinking 3s, rotating 5s linear 3s, shrinkingback 3s 8s;
}
'''
```

I tried to put each animation in different selectors. I tried to put the transformations in the same keyframe class. I tried applying the scaling on the html element with the rotation on the body tag. Is this possible at all, if not with css maybe with javascript? If it is please guide me there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `rotating` animation to

```
@keyframes rotating {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.5);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.5);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.5);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.5);
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.5);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(0.5);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(0.5);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(0.5);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(0.5);
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(0.5);
  }
}
```

This keeps body scaled out during rotation.